# Is there a time complexity difference between these two methods of list traversal?

Tags: python, python-3.x, algorithm, time-complexity

Is there a difference in time complexity? Or are they the same? I am not sure how to tell.

```
list_of_dict = [{'name':'alan', 'age':5}, {'name':'alice', 'age':6}]

# first method
names = []
ages  = []
for i in range(len(list_of_dict)):
    names.append(list_of_dict[i]['name'])
    ages.append(list_of_dict[i]['age'])

# second method

names = [x['name'] for x in list_of_dict]
ages  = [x['age'] for x in list_of_dict]
```

Any assistance or recommendations regarding this issue would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In terms of asymptotic time complexity, they are the same.

Both methods require constant dictionary access (which is constant time on average), for each element in the list, so `O(n)` for both.

If you care about constants though, it will be hard to tell, and might vary between different interpreters, which might optimize different things.

Comment: How can you tell they are the same if I may ask? I cant formally explain why. But it seems that the second one is "longer" since it iterates through the list twice

Comment: @Alan In terms of asymptotic time complexity, `O(n) = O(2*n)`.

Answer (score 2):

beside theoretical complexity, you can time them if you want or use `ipython` to do it using `%timeit`

first method: `10 loops, best of 3: 58.2 ms per loop`

second method: `10 loops, best of 3: 56.3 ms per loop`

they are quite close, to be checked with a larger dataset.